# toDataURL vs toDataURLHD

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I see that there are some new (ish) functions being proposed; `toDataURLHD`, `toBlobHD`, `getImageDataHD`, etc. which "returns [data] at the native canvas bitmap resolution" (http://developers.whatwg.org/the-canvas-element.html).

But I don't understand the terminology. Does that mean that there are situations where the non-HD versions will rescale the image data before returning it? (i.e. on a high-resolution display could `toDataURL` produce an image which is lower quality than the actual canvas), or is this just referring to the pixels-per-inch metadata in the image?

I've been experimenting with as many scaling methods as I can think of (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SktKQ/) and it always seems to be pixel-for-pixel, but that's hardly conclusive and I don't have access to any high-resolution displays to test on.

All I'm looking for is: can I rely on `toDataURL` & Co. producing pixel-for-pixel copies of my canvas, which have width and height exactly equal to the *attributes* set on the element? (and if so, what's the point of the HD versions?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WhatWG documents on canvas](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html) say the following:

> The size of the coordinate space does not necessarily represent the size of the actual 
>   bitmaps that the user agent will use internally or during rendering. On high-definition 
>   displays, for instance, the user agent may internally use bitmaps with two device pixels per 
>   unit in the coordinate space, so that the rendering remains at high quality throughout. 
>   Anti-aliasing can similarly be implemented using over-sampling with bitmaps of a higher 
>   resolution than the final image on the display.

And

> The toDataURL() method returns the data at a resolution of 96dpi.
>   The toDataURLHD() method returns it at the native canvas bitmap resolution.

How I understand this is that the `toDataURL` just returns CSS pixels (at 96 DPI); but the implementation is free to use higher pixel density that would be only visible through `toDataURLHD`. That is, even if you define your canvas as 800x600, being a CSS pixel size, an implementation could actually use 192 DPI density (1600x1200); if you use the former, you get 800x600, whereas the `HD` method would get you the actual pixels, guaranteed.

Furthermore the following is stated:

> Thus, in the 2D context, calling the drawImage() method to render the output of the
>   toDataURLHD() method to the canvas, given the appropriate dimensions, has no visible effect.

However it is not guaranteed that using the image data from `toDataURL` would not have a visible effect (being of worse resolution).

Comment: Not a possibility I'd thought of. So, if I set a canvas to be 100x100 on a display with 2x resolution, I *might* actually get a canvas with a size of 200x200 (displayed at 100x100). In that case, `toDataURL` would give an image of size 100x100 (scaled down by some method), but `toDataURLHD` would give the pixel-for-pixel 200x200 image. Does that fit with your understanding of it? (related question: can I force it not to produce a larger image on high resolution displays?)

Comment: I think that is my understanding too, however I just read the documents. I think this is for devices such as the new retina displays on Apple stuff; they can take use of the extended rendering capabilities of the devices while at the same time laying out the same way.

Comment: As for the "forcing it not to produce a larger image", then I couldn't find an answer either way

Comment: Note as of today, `toDataURLHD` still does not exist. It is neither supported in Chrome nor mentioned in MDN's docs.

Comment: Actually as of today, if your canvas displays as 100 x 100, `toDataURL()` gives you a 200 x 200 image under 2x resolution screen. And I'm trying to find a way to get 100 x 100 image.

Comment: @Xinan hmm, interesting :D

Comment: any news on this?